# iPhone send user location to PHP script

Tags: iphone, sdk

Hi I am currently designing my second iphone app, and having a small issue.
I have the location code working correctly but I have no idea how to send the label with the location info to my server.

I was wondering and hoping someone might be able to help.

Thanks
Russell

Answer (score 1):

That would depend entirely on what your PHP script expects to receive. Your most obvious choices would be to put the coordinates in the query string or in a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

Use ASIHTTPRequest for http requests. http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Josh" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Highland" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request start];
```